# Scala Spark's dataframe.limit(n) causes shuffling

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to limit the dataframe's output before writing to disk. An option is to use

```
df.limit(n)
```

but this built-in `limit` causes expensive shuffling. I also found a hacky way to get around with

```
df.rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 < fetchSize).map(_._1)
```

but I'm afraid this would cause unnecessary overheads due to extra execution of `zipWithIndex`, `filter` and `map`. Is there a better way to make use of the built-in `limit` without shuffling the data? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the specific n first lines of your dataframe or any lines would be good? You could use `sample` to decrease size of your dataset and it does not cause shuffle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just checked and it seems that `sample(double fraction)` requires me to know the input size to accurately limit the output size, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. Is there another way?

Comment: How zipWithIndex can help you here? it just creates indexes 0,1,2 and so on  (it's not grouping and counting etc)