# Spark what is most efficient dataframe way to find top N without shuffling and sorting

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've found many answers at StackOverflow how to find top N records.

For example:

```
df.filter("f==2").groupBy("a", "b",  "c").count().sort(desc("count"))
.limit(N)
```

I don't like this solution because:

- sorting/shuffling is not efficient
- the limit function takes all the partition data into one node

I found answer at StackOverflow ( [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619121/dataframe-orderby-followed-by-limit-in-spark), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458611/scala-sparks-dataframe-limitn-causes-shuffling)) (but they do **NOT** have example for the illustration) . They to use the following schema:

```
groupBy -> rdd > zipWithIndex
```

but I don't really understand how zipIndex can help me here. For example:

```
df.filter("f==2").groupBy("a", "b",  "c").count().rdd.zipWithIndex().collect()
```

Result looks like this:

```
Array(
([1,2,3,100   ],0),
([3,2,1,200   ],1), 
...
)
```

index just increments ...  so I'm not sure if it's solution...

Comment: it is not a solution

Comment: can you please provide me with some more information?

Comment: Your last comment is correct imo

Comment: if `N` is small you could try to broadcast a PriorityQueue and do `df.foreachPartition { <add to PQ and remove head if size exceeds N>}` This way you avoid data shuffle.

Comment: Could you please provide me with the answer code and I'll mark the question as "answered"